# Why (apply and '(1 2 3)) doesn't work while (and 1 2 3) works in R5RS?

Tags: lisp, scheme

I tried it in Racket like this

```
> (apply and '(1 2 3))
. and: bad syntax in: and
> (and 1 2 3)
3
```

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: Because `and` is a macro, not a function.

Comment: If the question is duplicate but the answers seem to add additional info then is there any way to blend two questions into on?

Answer (score 11):

`and` is not a function, it's a macro, so you cannot pass it around like a function.

The reason `and` is a macro, is to enable short-circuiting behaviour. You can make your own non-short-circuiting version:

```
(define (my-and . items)
  (if (null? items) #t
      (let loop ((test (car items))
                 (rest (cdr items)))
        (cond ((null? rest) test)
              (test (loop (car rest) (cdr rest)))
              (else #f)))))
```

and `my-and` *can* be used with `apply`.

For comparison, here's what the macro (which does do short-circuiting) looks like:

```
(define-syntax and
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((and) #t)
    ((and test) test)
    ((and test rest ...) (if test
                             (and rest ...)
                             #f))))
```

Answer (score 11):

Chris Jester-Young's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17233074/1281433) is right, but there's one other point I want to highlight. The standard `and` operator is a macro which delays the evaluation of its arguments, by (essentially, if not exactly) turning `(and a b c)` into `(if a (if b c #f) #f)`.  This means that if `a` is false, `b` and `c` do not get evaluated.

We also have the option of defining an `and-function` such that `(and-function a b c)` evaluates `a`, `b`, and `c`, and returns true when the values are all true.  This means that all of `a`, `b`, and `c` get evaluated.  `and-function` has the nice property that you can pass it around as function because it is a function.

There's still one option that seems to be missing:  an `and-function-delaying-evaluation` that returns return if and only if `a`, `b`, and `c` all return true, but that doesn't evaluate, e.g., `b` and `c` if `a` produces false.  This can be had, actually, with a function `and-funcalling-function` that requires its arguments to be a list of functions.  For instance:

```lisp
(define (and-funcalling-function functions)
  (or (null? functions)
      (and ((car functions))
           (and-funcalling-function (cdr functions)))))

(and-funcalling-function 
 (list (lambda () (even? 2))
       (lambda () (odd? 3))))
; => #t

(and-funcalling-function 
 (list (lambda () (odd? 2))
       (lambda () (even? 3)))) ; (even? 3) does not get evaluated
; => #f
```

Using a macro and this idiom, we can actually implement something with the standard `and` semantics:

```lisp
(define-syntax standard-and
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((standard-and form ...)
     (and-funcalling-function (list (lambda () form) ...)))))

(macroexpand '(standard-and (odd? 2) (even? 3)))
; =>
; (and-funcalling-function 
;  (list (lambda () (odd? 2))
;        (lambda () (even? 3))))
```

The lesson to take away from this, of course, is that you can have an `and`-like function that you can pass around and still get delayed evaluation;  you just need to delay evaluation by wrapping things in functions and letting the `and`-like function *call* those functions to produce values.  (In Scheme, this might be an opportunity to use promises.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Thanks for the edit!  I know that I mentioned translating, but I never did get around to it.  The post it much more in line with the question now.  Thanks!