# How to pass `and` as a function in Racket?

Tags: function, macros, lisp, scheme, racket

For the following code:

```
(foldl and #t '(#t #f))
```

Racket returns:

```
and: bad syntax in: and
```

I know `and` is not a function. And I can circumvent this problem using `lambda`:

```
(foldl (lambda (a b) (and a b)) #t '(#t #f))
```

I have 2 questions here:

1. `and` is not a function. Then what is it? Is it a macro?
2. My solution using `lambda` seems ugly. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: You can always prettify it with srfi-26 (cut)

Comment: @jozefg you mean `(foldl (cut and <> <>) #t '(#t #f))`? But [SRFI-26](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi-std/srfi-26.html?q=cut#cut) also says that `(cut if <> 0 1)` is illegal because `if` is not "an expression in the sense of R5RS" - which would seem to make `and` illegal as well there.

Comment: @WillNess It tests fine for me with racket 5.3. Whether this is implementation specific or not I'm not sure

Comment: You might be interested in [one of my answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17234845/1281433) in another similar question (possibly a duplicate) that looks at some possible ways of getting `and`-like functions, both non-short circuiting (like the one you provided in the question) and short-circuiting.

Comment: @jozefg That something works in one implementation does not mean that @WillNess is wrong. Since `and` is library syntax for `if` `(cut and ...)` is the same as `(cut if ...)`. Since the SRFI says it's illegal you can expect undefined behaviour and should avoid it.

Comment: @Sylwester That's why I said "I'm not sure if this is implementation specific" :)

Comment: @jozefg actually, SRFI-26 says `if` "not an expression in the sense of R5RS" and gives a link which defines the relevant `expr` case as `variable`, and defines `variable` as "not syntax", and also defines `and` as "syntax"; so in *Scheme* it *shouldn't* work. But Racket is not Scheme. :)

Comment: @Sylwester btw in SO only the first `@` designation fires up a notification; any others are ignored. :)

Comment: @jozefg `(begin (define x "hello") (string-set! x 0 #\H) x)` evaluates to "Hello" in most implementations. A R6RS **should** raise &assertion exception, but like R5RS it doesn't have to. Only when the report writes "an exception is raised" do they really have to. By not demanding anything in an implementation the responsibility is pushed to the developer not to write such violating, bad code like `(cut and <> <>)` because it might evaluate to 'hazy. @WillNess I'll keep it in mind :)

Comment: @Sylwester I'm aware of what undefined behavior is, I acknowledged that it was possible that it was UB, it was merely an observation. You're completely right, I just wasn't aware that it was ub and made an observation based on that.

Comment: @jozefg BTW we really need `(lambda (a b) (and b a))`, so the `cut` just won't cut it here. :) But thanks for bringing it up and thus triggering a discussion. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a [conditional](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html) [syntactic form](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax.html), or it might be implemented as a macro that expands to some [core syntax form](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-model.html#%28part._fully-expanded%29), which is treated as a special case by the compiler/interpreter.

[The list there in Racket's docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-model.html#%28part._fully-expanded%29) includes `if` as a special form but doesn't include `and`, so the latter most probably is implemented in terms of the former. But [R5RS does list `and` as a syntactic keyword](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_7.1.1). So, best we can say, it's either a special syntax, or a macro.

It is easy to re-write any `and` form `(and a b c ...)` as an `if` form, `(if a (if b (if c #t #f) #f) #f)`.

`lambda` is fine by me, but you can also use [`every` from SRFI-1](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi-std/srfi-1.html?q=#every) (or [Racket's `andmap`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=andmap#(def._((lib._racket/private/map..rkt)._andmap)))):

```
(every identity '(#t #f))
```

[should return `#f`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._identity%29%29).

*edit:* except, [as Joshua Taylor points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919327/how-to-pass-and-as-a-function-in-racket/17919617#comment26186378_17919327), calling your `lambda` through a function like `foldl` does not short-circuit. Which defeats the purpose to calling the `and` in the first place.

Another thing is, in [Racket's `foldl`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=andmap#(def._((lib._racket/private/list..rkt)._foldl))) the *last* argument to `lambda` is the one that receives the previous result in the chain of applications; so the implementation should really be

```
(foldl (lambda (a b) (and b a)) #t '(#t #f))
```