# SICP: Can or be defined in lisp as a syntactic transformation without gensym?

Tags: macros, lisp, scheme, sicp

I am trying to solve the last part of question 4.4 of the Structure and Interpretation of computer programming; the task is to implement **or** as a syntactic transformation. Only elementary syntactic forms are defined; quote, if, begin, cond, define, apply and lambda.

(or a b ... c) is equal to the first true value or false if no value is true.

The way I **want** to approach it is to transform for example (or a b c) into

```
(if a a (if b b (if c c false)))
```

the problem with this is that a, b, and c would be evaluated twice, which could give incorrect results if any of them had side-effects. So I want something like a let

```
(let ((syma a)) 
     (if syma syma (let ((symb b)) 
                        (if symb symb (let ((symc c))
                                           (if (symc symc false)) )) )) )
```

and this in turn could be implemented via lambda as in Exercise 4.6. The problem now is determining symbols syma, symb and symc; if for example the expression b contains a reference to the variable syma, then the let will destroy the binding. Thus we must have that syma is a symbol not in b or c.

Now we hit a snag; the only way I can see out of this hole is to have symbols that **cannot** have been in any expression passed to eval. (This includes symbols that might have been passed in by other syntactic transformations).

However because I don't have direct access to the environment at the expression I'm not sure if there is any reasonable way of producing such symbols; I think Common Lisp has the function gensym for this purpose (which would mean sticking state in the metacircular interpreter, endangering any concurrent use).

Am I missing something? Is there a way to implement or without using gensym? I know that Scheme has it's own hygenic macro system, but I haven't grokked how it works and I'm not sure whether it's got a gensym underneath.

Comment: In Common Lisp `GENSYM` is useful. But the real mechanism behind it is that one uses uninterned symbols in Common Lisp. Since these are unique symbols which are not interned in a package (a symbol namespace) there won't be collisions.

Comment: The question isn't a duplicate, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17234845/1281433) provides a solution for the case of `and` in Common Lisp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you might want to do here is to transform to a syntactic expansion where the evaluation of the various forms aren't nested.  You could do this, e.g., by wrapping each form as a `lambda` function  and then the approach that you're using is fine.  E.g., you can do turn something like

```
(or a b c)
```

into

```
(let ((l1 (lambda () a))
      (l2 (lambda () b))
      (l3 (lambda () c)))
  (let ((v1 (l1)))
    (if v1 v1
      (let ((v2 (l2)))
        (if v2 v2
          (let ((v3 (l3)))
            (if v3 v3
              false)))))))
```

(Actually, the evaluation of the `lambda` function *calls* are still nested in the `if`s and `let`s, but the definition of the `lambda` functions are in a location such that calling them in the nested `if`s and `let`s doesn't cause any difficulty with captured bindings.)  This doesn't address the issue of *how* you get the variables `l1`–`l3` and `v1`–`v3`, but that doesn't matter so much, none of them are in scope for the bodies of the `lambda` functions, so you don't need to worry about whether they appear in the body or not.  In fact, you can use the *same* variable for all the results:

```
(let ((l1 (lambda () a))
      (l2 (lambda () b))
      (l3 (lambda () c)))
  (let ((v (l1)))
    (if v v
      (let ((v (l2)))
        (if v v
          (let ((v (l3)))
            (if v v
              false)))))))
```

At this point, you're really just doing loop unrolling of a more general form like:

```
(define (functional-or . functions)
  (if (null? functions)
      false
      (let ((v ((first functions))))
        (if v v
            (functional-or (rest functions))))))
```

and the expansion of `(or a b c)` is simply

```
(functional-or (lambda () a) (lambda () b) (lambda () c))
```

This approach is also used in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17234845/1281433) to [Why (apply and '(1 2 3)) doesn't work while (and 1 2 3) works in R5RS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232240/why-apply-and-1-2-3-doesnt-work-while-and-1-2-3-works-in-r5rs/17234845#17234845).  And none of this required any `GENSYM`ing!

Comment: Nice solution with using closures, but your `functional-or` does not make '(or a b c) into `'(let ((l1 (lambda ... `. It's more like an implementation of `or` as special form rather than derived syntax.

Comment: @Sylwester Definitely;  the second ‘expansion’ is really the syntactic transformation.  I was just pointing out with the last form that that expansion is what you'd get from loop unrolling (or, in the case for Scheme, tail-recursive function unrolling).

Comment: you can avoid `l1`, `l2`, `l3` either, by using `(let ((funcs (list (lambda()a) (lambda()b) (lambda()c)))) (let ((v ((car funcs)))) ... (let ((v ((car (cdr funcs))))) ... (let ((v ((car (cdr (cdr funcs)))))) ...`. The expanding code knows the total number of functions in `funcs`. Of course using `functional-or` is nicer. :)

Answer (score 1):

In SICP you are given two ways of implementing or. One that handles them as special forms which is trivial and one as derived expressions. I'm unsure if they actually thought you would see this as a problem, but you can do it by implementing `gensym` or altering `variable?` and how you make derived variables like this:

```
;; a unique tag to identify special variables
(define id (vector 'id))

;; a way to make such variable
(define (make-var x)
  (list id x))

;; redefine variable? to handle macro-variables
(define (variable? exp) 
  (or (symbol? exp)
      (tagged-list? exp id)))


;; makes combinations so that you don't evaluate
;; every part twice in case of side effects (set!)
(define (or->combination terms)
  (if (null? terms)
      'false
      (let ((tmp (make-var 'tmp)))
        (list (make-lambda (list tmp)
                           (list (make-if tmp 
                                    tmp 
                                    (or->combination (cdr terms)))))
              (car terms)))))


;; My original version
;; This might not be good since it uses backquotes not introduced 
;; until chapter 5 and uses features from exercise 4.6
;; Though, might be easier to read for some so I'll leave it.
(define (or->combination terms)
  (if (null? terms)
      'false
      (let ((tmp (make-var 'tmp)))
        `(let ((,tmp ,(car terms)))
           (if ,tmp
               ,tmp
               ,(or->combination (cdr terms)))))))
```

How it works is that `make-var` creates a new list every time it is called, even with the same argument. Since it has `id` as it's first element `variable?` will identify it as a variable. Since it's a list it will only match in variable lookup with `eq?` if it is the same list, so several nested or->combination tmp-vars will all be seen as different by `lookup-variable-value` since `(eq? (list) (list)) => #f` and special variables being lists they will never shadow any symbol in code.

This is influenced by [eiod](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-46/eiod.scm), by Al Petrofsky, which implements syntax-rules in a similar manner. Unless you look at others implementations as spoilers you should give it a read.

Comment: is there a typo in your `variable?` definition? Does SICP evaluator support backquote?

Comment: @WillNess Yes it was :). All 3 procedures are to be used by the evaluator so only the result of or->if is actually evaluated by the evaluator and the backquote is evaluated by the host. If `or` was a evaluator level macro, like we could define in `eiod`,  we would need something similar to or->if on a higher level to do the lexical scope variable, temporaries and bound patters on the outside.

Comment: I asked the wrong question. I meant, are we allowed to use backquote in the implementation. I don't think I ever saw it in the book. But  we could  of course always replace it with a hand buit list, so this perhaps is not a problem.

Comment: @WillNess Point taken. It's touched in chapter 5, but not much and I used let which wasn't available until 4.6. I rewrote it, but also  left the original since it I still think it's easier to see the essence of it (though that might be true only for seasoned lispers)

Comment: Now this just needs a clarification on how the new vars mechanism depends on `eq?`-inequality of freshly allocated lists, [guaranteed by the Scheme Report](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_216). Or does it go without saying? :)