# Using foldr with the or logical operator in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm attempting to run the following bit of code in Scheme using Dr.Racket

```
(foldr or #f '(#f #f #f #t))
```

Now, I expected this to work because

```
(foldr + 0 '(1 2 3))
```

Worked just fine, returning 6.

But when I try to run it with the logical or I get "or: bad syntax in: or"

What am I doing wrong? Also, is there an alternative method to calculate the or of a list without using folds, perhaps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why (apply and '(1 2 3)) doesn't work while (and 1 2 3) works in R5RS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232240/why-apply-and-1-2-3-doesnt-work-while-and-1-2-3-works-in-r5rs)

Comment: Some implementation have the function boolean/or which works as expected. But using foldr and boolean/or may not be the best solution as they won't short-circuit once you find a true condition. It will go ahead and fold the whole list.

Answer (score 5):

In the specific case of folding `or`, you should use [`ormap`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._ormap%29%29). You can pass in [`identity`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._identity%29%29) (or even [`values`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/values.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._values%29%29) ) as the function to use with `ormap`.

```
> (ormap identity '(#f #f #f #f #t))
#t
> (ormap identity '(#f #f #f #f #f))
#f
```

In general, you can only fold functions, not macros, and `or` is a macro because it has short-circuiting behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

My Scheme is fairly weak, but if I'm not mistaken, or is a macro, not a function, so you can't pass it around in higher-order calls.  You can wrap it in a lambda, however, leading to the less-pleasant looking:

```
(foldr (lambda (a b) (or a b)) #f '(#f #f #f #t)) => #t
```

If you know the number of arguments in advance, it's worth noting that or takes zero or more arguments:

```
(or) => #f
(or #f) => #f
(or #t) => #t
(or #t #f) => #t
(or #f #f #f #f #f) => #f
```

Otherwise, you'll need a more experienced Schemer than me to provide the answer.

Comment: I see that one's already arrived.  Chris's ormap is just the ticket.