# How is 'and' defined in Scheme？

Tags: scheme, racket

'and' in Scheme will ignore the error 'division by 0', like (and (negative? (random 100)) (/ 1 0)) returns #f.
How does it do that?

i (define (∧ b₀ b₁) (if (not b₀) #f b₁)), (∧ (negative? (random 100)) (/ 1 0)) still goes into a 'division by 0' error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why (apply and '(1 2 3)) doesn't work while (and 1 2 3) works in R5RS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232240/why-apply-and-1-2-3-doesnt-work-while-and-1-2-3-works-in-r5rs)

Answer (score 5):

You can't define `and` directly as a function because Scheme is *strict*--this means that function arguments are always evaluated before being passed to the function.

However, you can define a proper short-circuiting `and` using a macro. Here's the simplest version in Racket:

```
(define-syntax-rule (my-and a b) (if a b #f))
```

or the equivalent form using `syntax-rules` which is in standard Scheme:

```
(define-syntax my-and
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ a b) (if a b #f)]))
```

A macro is not a normal function. Instead, it's a syntactic transformation that runs at compile-time. When you use your new `and` in your code, it gets "expanded" to the corresponding `if` expression. So:

```
(my-and #f (/ 1 0))
```

gets transformed into

```
(if #f (/ 1 0) #f)
```

before your program is run. Since `if` is built into the language, this has the correct behavior.

Since macros are not functions, it also means you can't pass around as arguments. So you can't write a fold using `and` directly--you'd have to wrap it into a lambda.

To be more faithful to the original `and`, you could define `my-and` to take an arbitrary number of arguments by making the macro recursive. To define a "rest parameter" in a macro, you use the special `...` keyword:

```
(define-syntax my-and
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_)         #t]
    [(_ a)       a]
    [(_ a b ...) (if a (my-and b ...) #f)]))
```

If you were using a lazy language like Racket's `#lang lazy` or Haskell instead, you would not need to use macros here. You could just define `and` directly:

```
#lang lazy
(define (and a b) (if a b #f))
```

or in Haskell:

```
and a b = if a then b else False
```

and it would have the correct behavior, as a normal function. You would be able to pass this `and` to a fold, and it would even stop evaluating the list as soon as it encountered a `False`! Take a look:

```
Prelude> foldl and True [True, False, error "fail"]
False
```

(`error` in Haskell errors out just like `1/0`. Since Haskell is statically typed, the arguments to `and` have to be booleans so you can't use `1/0` directly.)

Comment: To be clear, a macro is a compile time creature that rewrites your scheme program AST. Think of it like a function from `AST -> AST` thats run at compile time

Comment: If i do (define ∧ (λ (b₀ b₁) (if b₀ (b₁) #f))), can i use a macro to change (∧ (negative? (random 324)) (/ 1 0)) into (∧ (negative? (random 324)) (λ () (/ 1 0)))?

Comment: @user2951219: I don't think having a macro and a function with the same name is a good idea. Instead, you could just define `∧` as a macro directly. This is how the standard library's `and` works. However, if you give them different names (say you call the macro `and-macro` or something), wrapping things in lambdas should work too.

Comment: Can I do (f ∧ (negative? (random 100)) (/ 1 0))), where f is a macro and ^ is a function? f just do the thunk things.

Comment: @user2951219: Sure, but I don't think that's the best way to do this. Either make `and` a macro directly with `if` or wrap its arguments in lambdas and call a normal function.

Comment: What do you mean by 'wrap its arguments in lambdas and call a normal function'?

Comment: @user2951219: Like your first example. First write a function like `(define (and-fn a b) (if a (b) #f))` then write a macro that expands `(and a b)` into `(and-fn a (lambda () b))`.

Comment: what if i need the macro not only for 'and'？Like it contains a function expression, zero or more argument expressions,and it calls the (value of) the function expression, on zero-arity functions whose bodies are the argument expressions.

Comment: @jozefg: there's no need for "think of" analogies -- in Racket, this is *exactly* what macros are: functions from syntax to syntax (which is a different type than lists etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Like most languages, Scheme's logical `AND` uses short circuit evaluation, which means its right operand will only be evaluated if the left operand is true. If the left operand is false, then the result of the expression must be false regardless of the value of the right operand, so if the left operand evaluates to false, it returns false immediately, without evaluating the right operand at all.

To be precise, here's the language from the spec (I'm section 4.2.1 of R5RS, but this isn't an area that's likely to change must between revisions of the spec):

`(and <test`<sub>1</sub>`>` `... )`

> The `<test>` expressions are evaluated from left to right, and the value of the first expression that evaluates to a false value (see section 6.3.1) is returned. Any remaining expressions are not evaluated.

Comment: I know the algorithm, but i (define (∧ b₀ b₁) (if (not b₀) #f b₁)), (∧ (negative? (random 100)) (/ 1 0)) still goes into a 'division by 0' error.

Comment: @user2951219 That's because whenever you're doing `(∧ exp1 exp2)`, which is a _procedure application_, both the forms `exp1` and `exp2` must be _evaluated before_ the procedure can be called.  That's the point of macros;  you can “get around” the typical evaluation rules.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean shortcutting.  The first argument to "and" evaluates to false, therefore the result must be false, and there's no reason for it to evaluate the second argument (and therefore incur the error).

Comment: I know the algorithm, but i  (define (∧ b₀ b₁) (if (not b₀) #f b₁)), (∧ (negative? (random 100)) (/ 1 0)) still goes into a 'division by 0' error.